# Is there a name for this digit?

Tags: terminology, number-systems

I am currently working on a problem where it is useful to consider the index of the last digit in a number which is not a $9$.

For example in the number $$a=8243848392842992999,$$ the index I care about is $3$ because the coefficient of $10^3$ is the first base-$10$ digit which is not a 9.
$$a = 9 + 9 * 10 + 9 * 10^2 + 2 * 10^3 + \cdots.$$

More generally, we could ask the question in any base, for the first index of a $p$-ary digit which is not $p-1$.
In base $3$, this might look something like
$$b = 0120120220220212211112$$
having the index I care about being $1$ because $$b = 2 + 1*3 + \cdots.$$

I could call this the "first nonpenultimate digit" but that seems like a confusing name. I was wondering if a name for such an index had already been agreed upon?

Comment: That is the number of trailing zeros in $a+1$, isnt't it? I doubt that there is a dedicated name.

Comment: Yes exactly. I wish there were a dedicated name.

Comment: Probably no dedicated name. If you are writing a longish document that uses this idea, just make up a good short name and provide a proper definition with a few examples. It will be a function of the number and the base.

Comment: "I could call this the "first nonpenultimate digit" but that seems like a confusing name. "  Then call it something else.  Call it "first digit that is not $9$" and explain what you mean the first time you use it.  Or call it "shirley" and explain what you mean the first time you use it.

Comment: Name suggestion: The nope digit. Playing off of 'no'n-'pe'nultimate... just a suggestion

Comment: If you give it an awkward name, and then others use it later, they may call it "the tekay digit"!

Answer (score 0):

Relying on Martin R's comment, for a prime $p$, it is the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) of $b + 1$, denoted $v_p(b+1)$.